# Ubuntu Boots to Shell

Tags: boot, command-line, raspberrypi, 21.04

Every time I boot up my computer it shows this

```
`-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
```

`ALERT!  LABEL=writable does not exist. Dropping to a shell!`

`BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-6ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash)`

`Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands`

Is there any way that I can fix this and make it boot?

Comment: You've got something wrong in your configuration.  Do you have any custom bootable devices?  Or is this just an RPi running off of an SD card?  `LABEL=writable` suggests you had some other partition or drive on the system that is no longer present and as such it has broken the boot process.

Comment: I didn't have an SD card to my knowledge, but it is booting off of a hard drive

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when migrating my Raspberry Pi3 boot/root partitions to a different SD card. I fixed it by inserting the SDcard into a running linux system and setting the label onto the appropriate root (/) filesystem partition:

```
e2label /dev/sdg2 writable
```

As per instructions here:
https://www.tecmint.com/change-modify-linux-disk-partition-label-names/

After doing this, the Pi boot loader was able to find this partition with label "writable" and complete its boot.